# How perform iis compression on DNN website

Tags: iis, optimization, dotnetnuke

DNN does not support gzip compression and it is recommended to use iis compression. I fail to find a good tutorial on it. Can someone please guide me on how to do iis compression

Comment: Is the lack of compression actually the problem?

Comment: yes it is, the site is taking a lot of time to load and according to performance reports compression is a high priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer thanks to posting on DNN forums. I will not be looking in Gzip compression for now. Will look into server first to determine if website speed can be improved.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/198/threadid/526186/scope/posts